# Validation based on role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Right so I have one user table with different users. I need to validate user tables on update prior to them moving onto the main site.

so far I've just done the following, is there a way I can block the validations depending on a role without doing a custom validation method, like with_options :on => :update

before_validation :check_role

```
if check_role = "developer" do |dev|
    dev.validate :first_name, presence: true # this doesn't work btw...
end

 def check_role
     return self.role_type unless self.role_type == nil
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out and this looks like the best way to do it:

```
class YourModel 

  with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.whatever == "whatever" } do |on_condition|
    on_condition.validates_presence_of :address
    on_condition.validates_presence_of :city
  end

  with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.condition_the_second == "whatever" } do |on_condition|
    on_condition.validates_presence_of :foo
    on_condition.validates_presence_of :bar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with_options :if => Proc.new {|user| user.role_type == 'developer'} do |developer|
  developer.validates :first_name, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Will I have to do that proc for every single column or can I call it in a block?

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, if: :developer?

def developer?
  role == 'developer'
end
```

Comment: I wanted to do it in a block so I can do all the validations without using the if on every line. Keeping it DRY...

Comment: You can combine validation conditions in order to use `if` only once.